# Gitlab lint interface for dockerfiles

Tags: docker, gitlab

Just like the gitlab-ci linting , we want to have a linter for dockerfiles in our repositories to encourage following company-wide best practises without enforcing them.

Is there an interface or plugin for gitlab or how would you archive such behaviour?

Setting up a CICD is not a valid option - unless I can enforce it on all new projects be default.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like autodevops - https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/autodevops/#auto-code-quality may be a solution.